# OutOfMemory error in memory rdbms database what about in hazelcast

Tags: hazelcast

We have a continuously increasing data which is 1 gb in 10 minutes. We want to save this data in disk for further processing like SQL queries.

Can we store it via hazelcast like save the data to disk if it is bigger than 500 mb and use the 500 mb data for in memory computing and so on.

What is the solution big data technology for such a usage? We use 32 bit Windows XP.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [IMap](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest-development/manual/html/Distributed_Data_Structures/Map/Getting_Map_and_Putting_Entries.html) and can configure [map-store](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest-development/manual/html/Distributed_Data_Structures/Map/Loading_and_Storing_Persistent_Data.html) and [eviction](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest-development/manual/html/Distributed_Data_Structures/Map/Map_Eviction.html) for it.

With map-store, entries in IMap is stored into db and with eviction, you can control used memory.